# Нажимая на кнопку «Отправить вопрос», соглашаешься с правилами или самим фактом использования сайта?

Tags: поддержка, справка, правила

При попытке задать вопрос анонимом:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, в тоже время, плашка снизу ставит перед фактом:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так, всё же, в какой момент пользователь подписывается под правилами?

Comment: Прочитали и поняли != согласились.

Comment: @Qwertiy хм. Действительно, разница есть. Но моё "понятие" правил вообще ни к чему не обязывает в итоге? Т.е, по сути, бесполезная плашка?

Comment: Полагаю, пока ты только читаешь, всем пофиг, согласен ты с правилами или нет - никто ведь даже не знает о твоём присутствии. А вот когда начинаешь пользоваться, то уже надо бы согласиться.

Comment: Тут бы еще порядок привести в порядок, но это на MSE надо. И вообще *курсив что-то выбивается здесь*.